# Ruby on Rails form_for attributes not being written to the model even though they are valid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, rspec, form-for

I'm creating a simple sign up form, and my rspec validations are failing

```
 (states: "Failure/Error: expect { click_button submit }.to change(User, :count).by(1)
   count should have been changed by 1, but was changed by 0")
```

when I submit (what looks like) a valid form. I am getting an error that my name fields can't be blank, however, they aren't. The parameters that are failing to save clearly exist and are present in my params variable. I am totally lost on what the issue is...

Sign Up Page:

```
<h1>Sign up</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="span6 offset3">
    <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
      <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>
      <%= f.label :first_name %>
      <%= f.text_field :first_name %>

      <%= f.label :last_name %>
      <%= f.text_field :last_name %>

      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.text_field :email %>

      <%= f.label :password %>
      <%= f.password_field :password %>

      <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %>
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>

      <%= f.submit "Create my account", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

User Controller

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end

def new
  @user = User.new
end

def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  if @user.save
    flash[:success] = "Welcome to the APP NAME!"
    redirect_to @user
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

HTML

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="span6 offset3">
    <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/users" class="new_user" id="new_user" method="post">
      <div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" />
        <input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="HOESbh8pxffYQlmMDYOFm/fBWt1OXOz3CZ4mdgiXMUM=" />
      </div>
      <div id="error_explanation">
        <div class="alert alert-error">
          The form contains 4 errors.
        </div>
        <ul>
          <li>* First name can&#39;t be blank</li>
          <li>* First name is too short (minimum is 2 characters)</li>
          <li>* Last name can&#39;t be blank</li>
          <li>* Last name is too short (minimum is 2 characters)</li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="field_with_errors"><label for="user_first_name">First name</label></div>
        <div class="field_with_errors"><input id="user_first_name" name="user[first_name]" type="text" /></div>

        <div class="field_with_errors"><label for="user_last_name">Last name</label></div>
        <div class="field_with_errors"><input id="user_last_name" name="user[last_name]" type="text" /></div>

        <label for="user_email">Email</label>
        <input id="user_email" name="user[email]" type="text" value="baz@uitest.com" />

        <label for="user_password">Password</label>
        <input id="user_password" name="user[password]" type="password" />

        <label for="user_password_confirmation">Confirmation</label>
        <input id="user_password_confirmation" name="user[password_confirmation]" type="password" />

        <input class="btn btn-large btn-primary" name="commit" type="submit" value="Create my account" />
    </form>    
  </div>
</div>
```

Params Variable after I save the the 'invalid' user:

```
--- !ruby/hash:ActionController::Parameters
utf8: ✓
authenticity_token: HOESbh8pxffYQlmMDYOFm/fBWt1OXOz3CZ4mdgiXMUM=
user: !ruby/hash:ActionController::Parameters
  first_name: First name test
  last_name: Last name test
  email: baz@uitest.com
  password: foobar
  password_confirmation: foobar
commit: Create my account
action: create
controller: users
```

Comment: In user model, the field for "name" is "first_name", "last_name", or just "name"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are missing the strong parameters.  There is a description here in the Ruby on Rails guides: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters

In your controller's `create` action, change `@user = User.new(user_params)` to something like `@user = User.new(profile_params)` and define a private `profile_params` method:

```
def profile_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
end
```

This will allow the controller to actually pass the values of the parameters to the model for your user to be created.

Comment: I had the strong params, but the fields included in them were incorrect, which is why they weren't being recognized. Thanks!